# Python: Variable not detected when defining in "if" function and using in another

Tags: python, variables

so I was making something using sqlite3 and I tried to execute something and it gave me an error saying that c was not defined even though it was defined above. I defined the cursor and connection in a previous if function, and in a new one I was unable to call it. I am new to sqlite3 and I'm trying to make a login for context. Heres the code:

```
import sqlite3
import os
ms = os.path.isfile("usp.db")
consent = input("Login?(Y/N): ")
if consent == "N" or consent == "n" and ms == False:
   conn = sqlite3.connect("usp.db")
   c = conn.cursor()
   c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS login (username TEXT, password TEXT)")
   conn.commit()
   print("Welcome! Enter your desired username and password!")
   username = input("What would you like your username to be?: ")
   password = input("What would you like your password to be?: ")
   c.execute("INSERT INTO login (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)", (username, password))
   conn.commit()
   conn.close()
elif consent == "Y" or consent == "y" and ms == False:
   print('It seems like you have not created an account. Restart and type "N" or "n" to create one!')
elif consent == "N" or consent == "n" and ms == True:
   print("It seems like you already have an account! Please login into that one!")
elif consent == "Y" or consent == "y" and ms == True:
   username_login = input("What is your username?: ")
   password_login = input("What is your password?: ")
   sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = ? AND password = ?"
   for row in c.execute(sql, [(username_login), (password_login)]):
      if row == username_login and row == password_login:
         print("Welcome back!")
```

and it gives me this

```
for row in c.execute(sql, [(username_login), (password_login)]): NameError: name 'c' is not defined
```

anyways thx for the help ik i explained it bad if u need clarification just ask I'm bad at explaining

Comment: On that line, `c` isn't defined - you're only defining `c` if `consent == "N" or consent == "n" and ms == False` and the line causes the error is in an `elif` block. Move the definition outside of the `if` statement if you need it in more places.

Comment: try to simplify your logic -- that code is a bit painful to read. Suggestion: `consent = input(...).lower()` to simplify all the 'N' or 'n' / 'Y' or 'y', etc. Also, it's often more readable to have one first test (file exists or not) and inside that the second (Y/N).

Comment: Sorry lol ik it’s rlly bad I’ve only been learning for a few weeks and I don’t know all the syntaxes about the .lower and stuff

Comment: I was thinking of putting it in the lines above the of statement but I was scared that it would keep making a new database every time and I tried to look for alternatives but I got no luck. Any ideas ?